# SVG Animation Stroke-Dasharray

Tags: css, svg, stroke-dasharray

I am animating this svg stroke changing the dasharray offset. Can both ends of the border be animated, instead of the left end be static and only the other end move and wrap around?

I am being forced to right more stuff here, let me know if it is clear or if I need to explain what I need in a better way. Thanks.

```html
<style>

    .wrapper{
        --height: 185px; 
        width: 300px;
        height: var(--height);
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .image, .image-border{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 12px !important;
    }
    
    .image{
        max-width: 96% !important;
        top: 1.3%;
        left: 1.8%;
    }
    
    .image-border{
        width: 100%;
        top: -2.3px;
    }
    
    .image-border path{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #824ad8;
        stroke-width: 2.3px;
        stroke-dasharray: 320;
        stroke-dashoffset: 320;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    
    .wrapper:hover .image-border path{
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        stroke-dasharray: 320;
        /*stroke-width: 2.3px;*/
    }
    
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    
    <img class="image" src="https://wordpress-513216-1810865.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Screen-Shot-2021-02-12-at-10.48.49-AM.jpg" />
    
    <svg class="image-border" viewBox="0 0 103 65" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke-linecap:round;">
        <path d="M1.146,4.244c-0,-1.71 1.388,-3.098 3.098,-3.098l93.804,-0c1.71,-0 3.098,1.388 3.098,3.098l-0,55.767c-0,1.71 -1.388,3.099 -3.098,3.099l-93.804,-0c-1.71,-0 -3.098,-1.389 -3.098,-3.099l-0,-55.767Z"/>
    </svg>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the `stroke-dasharray` so that it is twice smaller than when not hovered with a 0 length hole, **and** to move it to its initial position at the same time so that you have a full stroke correctly centered.

```css
.image-border path{
    fill: none;
    stroke: #824ad8;
    stroke-width: 2.3px;
    stroke-dasharray: 320;
    stroke-dashoffset: 320;
    transition: 1s;
}
.wrapper:hover .image-border path{
    stroke-dasharray: 160 0;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.wrapper{
    --height: 185px; 
    width: 300px;
    height: var(--height);
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.image, .image-border{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 12px !important;
}

.image{
    max-width: 96% !important;
    top: 1.3%;
    left: 1.8%;
}

.image-border{
    width: 100%;
    top: -2.3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <img class="image" src="https://wordpress-513216-1810865.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Screen-Shot-2021-02-12-at-10.48.49-AM.jpg" />
    
    <svg class="image-border" viewBox="0 0 103 65" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke-linecap:round;">
        <path d="M1.146,4.244c-0,-1.71 1.388,-3.098 3.098,-3.098l93.804,-0c1.71,-0 3.098,1.388 3.098,3.098l-0,55.767c-0,1.71 -1.388,3.099 -3.098,3.099l-93.804,-0c-1.71,-0 -3.098,-1.389 -3.098,-3.099l-0,-55.767Z"/>
    </svg>
    
</div>
```